# How to remove the intellij @range annotation?

Tags: intellij-idea

You can see that in jdk's InputStream.
[image]

Where did the @Range come from? How to remove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | General | Appearance, **Show external annotations inline**:

[image: Show external annotations inline]

See [External annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html) help section for more details.